# jQuery.fn.on() method - need to pass 'this' as function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to attach a click event to a button in wordpress, which needs to be dynamically scripted because different posts have different numbers of images in their gallery. I tried the following code without success, I think the this parameter handed to the function might refer to the '#primary' element rather than to the #nextPicButton (whose name atribute contains an index value) being clicked:

```
jquery('#primary').on("click", '#nextPicButton', function(){ nextPic(this,picMax); });
```

Does anyone know how I can make the 'this' argument refer to the '#nextPicButton' rather than anything else?

Comment: `...function(){ nextPic($(this),picMax); });` ??

Comment: Actually it turns out the code does function as intended, i.e. this is interpreted dynamically or as a closure or whatever...the code was faulty elsewhere...thanks Romeo Sierra anyways